# React Semantic UI - mobile view marginRight

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I use [react semantic ui](https://react.semantic-ui.com) for a little web app with the heroku react create app buildpack.

For some reason I always get a margin on the right of a fluid container. Chrome's inspector does not see the margin on the body, page or any other element.

Please see the pictures attached.

How do I get rid of this?

[image]
[image]

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import MainMenu from '../../components/menu';
import * from '../../components/search/searchComponents';
import {Button, Container, Image, Item, Label, Responsive, Segment} from 'semantic-ui-react';


/*START TESTDATA*/
const data= [
]
/*END TESTDATA*/

export default class Search extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            searchType: undefined,
            searchResults: [],
            showSearchResultDetails: false,
            mainSearchStyleHeight: 'calc(100vh - 40px)',
            mainSearchStylePTop: 'calc(33vh - 40px)',
            mainSearchStyleTransition: undefined,
        };
    }

    searchButtonHandleOnClick(){
        this.setState({
            mainSearchStyleHeight: '100%',
            mainSearchStylePTop: '2rem',
            mainSearchStylePBottom: '2rem',
            mainSearchStyleTransition: 'height: 1s ease-in',
            searchResults: dishes
        })
    }
    handleSearchResultOnClick(item){
        this.setState({showSearchResultDetails: true})
    }
    render() {
        /*TODO: add css transition here*/
        var mainSearchStyle = {
            height: this.state.mainSearchStyleHeight,
            paddingTop: this.state.mainSearchStylePTop,
            paddingBottom: this.state.mainSearchStylePBottom,
            transition: this.state.mainSearchStyleTransition
        }
        const searchBtn = <Button basic icon="search" content="Suchen" onClick={this.searchButtonHandleOnClick.bind(this)}/>
        return (
            <div>
                <MainMenu/>
                <Container fluid id="mainSearch" style={mainSearchStyle}>
                    <Container>
                        <Responsive as={Segment} minWidth={768} raised padded="very">
                            <SearchByAttr/>
                            <div className="txt-center mt-2">
                                {searchBtn}
                            </div>
                        </Responsive>
                        <Responsive maxWidth={767} className="pt-3 pb-3">
                            <SearchByAttr/>
                            <div className="txt-center mt-2">
                                {searchBtn}
                            </div>
                        </Responsive>
                    </Container>
                </Container>

                <Container id="mainSearchResults" className="p-1">
                    {/*TODO: move this to search components*/}
                    <Item.Group divided>
                        {this.state.searchResults.length > 0 && this.state.searchResults.map(item=>(
                            <Item key={item.name}>
                                <Image
                                    size="small"
                                    src='http://via.placeholder.com/300x250'
                                    label={{ color: 'blue', content: '4,90 Euro', icon: 'spoon', ribbon: true }}
                                />
                                <Item.Content>
                                    <Item.Header as='a' onClick={this.handleSearchResultOnClick.bind(this, item)}>
                                        {item.name}
                                        </Item.Header>
                                    <Item.Meta>
                                        <span className='cinema'>
                                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
                                        </span>
                                    </Item.Meta>
                                    <Item.Description>
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
                                        sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
                                        sed diam voluptua.
                                    </Item.Description>
                                    <Item.Extra>
                                        <Label content='vegan' />
                                        <Label content='laktosefrei' />
                                        <Label content='low carb' />
                                    </Item.Extra>
                                </Item.Content>
                            </Item>
                        ))}
                    </Item.Group>

                </Container>
                <SearchResultDetails
                    open={this.state.showSearchResultDetails}
                    onClose={()=>this.setState({showSearchResultDetails: false})}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

Comment: Which component did you use? can you post your code here?

Comment: please see the edited post

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing. Looks like it is not about the Responsive container. The whole page is off to the left, including menu. So the problem might be outside of this Component.

Try just render a Hello to see.

```
render() {
    return <div>Hello</div>
}
```